# Simplist way to display Arduino serial data in label

Tags: tkinter, pyserial, tkinter-layout

I have searched high and low. What is the smallest amount of code to show text of a  temprature reading from an arduino in a window that updates every second?

Comment: Are you asking us to do all the work for you? Stackoverflow isn’t a free code-writing service. There are many arduino+tkinter questions on this site. Have you done any research?

Comment: if you put all code in module then program may need only one line `import module`;)

Comment: Oh yes the work has been done and the research followed for 3 weeks now. The issue I keep comeng up against is the half knowledge I have with Python. Below is where I am at. I would put the 12 different attempsts I have made but it migh be a TLDR situation.

Comment: What i am trying todo is add a temp reading in the centre but am not winning.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial ('com24',9600)


class gui(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,master):
            tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,master)
            self.master = master
            self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):

            self.lounge = tkinter.Button(self, text="Lounge Lights",width=15,height=6,command=self.Lounge,font = "Times",bg="#42d7f4")
            self.lounge.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

            self.kitchen = tkinter.Button(self, text="Kitchen Lights",width=15,height=6,command=self.Kitchen,font = "Times",bg="#42d7f4")
            self.kitchen.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)

            self.bedroom = tkinter.Button(self, text="Bedroom Lights",width=15,height=6,command=self.Bedroom,font = "Times",bg="#42d7f4")
            self.bedroom.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5, padx=5)

            self.ph1 = tkinter.Label(self, text="TIME",width=15,height=6,font = "Times",bg="#42d7f4")
            self.ph1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, padx=5,sticky=tkinter.E)

            self.ph2 = tkinter.Label(self, text="Img",width=15,height=6,font = "Times",bg="#42d7f4")
            self.ph2.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=5, padx=5,sticky=tkinter.W)


    def Lounge(self,ll=[0]):
            ll[0] = not ll[0]
            if ll[0]:
                    self.lounge.configure(text = 'Lounge Lights OFF')
                    ser.write('a')
            else:
                    self.lounge.configure(text = 'Lounge Lights ON')
                    ser.write('d')

    def Kitchen(self,kl=[0]):
            kl[0] = not kl[0]
            if kl[0]:
                    self.kitchen.configure(text = 'Kitchen Lights OFF')
                    ser.write('b')
            else:
                    self.kitchen.configure(text = 'Kitchen Lights ON')
                    ser.write('e')

    def Bedroom(self,br=[0]):
            br[0] = not br[0]
            if br[0]:
                    self.bedroom.configure(text = 'Bedroom Lights OFF')
                    ser.write('c')
            else:
                    self.bedroom.configure(text = 'Bedroom Lights ON')
                    ser.write('f')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = gui(None)
    app.title("PyWiFiLiGhTs")
    app.mainloop()
```